# Multiple alerts due to method

Tags: javascript, function

I have a dynamic table which receives new rows using `append`.

Within each of those rows is a `td` where a number(quantity) is represented.

Either side of the number is a button(plus & minus).

Each time the button is pressed it appends using the `function append`.

Just testing the buttons function due to when the object exists on the page, i have used `alert()` to illustrate its functioning correctly, HOWEVER if i have created 6 rows, the alert occurs 6 times.

Now i understand why, as i am recalling the function that controls the quantity so it will work for each new row, on the button press in `function append()`.

The issue i have: Can/should i refresh a function for each row, without it essentially creating duplicates of the function. To my understanding i need to refresh each new row or the button will not 'exist' in order for the function to work on that button.

```
function append() {
    var adj_button_down = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm small-btn-quant-adj quant_adjust_down'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span> </button>";
    var adj_button_up = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm small-btn-quant-adj quant_adjust_up'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></button>";                             

    $( "#till__tablepanel_table_"+tablenumber ).append( "<tr id='"+ fullReference+newrownum +"'><td>"+ newrownum +"</td><td>"+value_infoTitle+"</td><td>"+adj_button_down+"<span id='"+ fullReference+newrownum +"_price' class='wrap quantity'>1</span>"+adj_button_up+"</td><td>&#163;"+value_unitPrice+"</td><td>&#163;<span>"+value_unitPrice+"</span></td></tr>" );

quantityAdjust();

}

function quantityAdjust() {
    quantAdjustUp();
}

function quantAdjustUp(){
    $(".quant_adjust_up").click( function() {
        alert("test success");
    });
}
```

Comment: `$(".quant_adjust_up").off('click').click(function(){})`

Comment: This is what happens when you add event handlers inside reccurring functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off the click handler first before reassigning:

```
$(".quant_adjust_up").off("click").on("click", function () {
      alert("test success");
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to actually solve the problem that's causing the event  handler to be bound multiple times ?

Comment: I guess if I wanted to be extra, extra thorough, I might also write his quantAdjustDown function, too, right? No thanks.

Comment: That was my thought @adeneo. This has solved the issue, but be that as it may has not made me feel ecstatic. Ideally, i was trying to find the "right" way to handle a function that needed to be refreshed when adding something to the DOM. Normally i would use `$.getscript`, however in this instance is just not feasible.

Comment: @StuartWickenden - Should be simple enough to solve, create the elements with the event handlers attached or use delegated event handlers, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of your stuff:

```
function append() {
    var adj_button_down = "...";
    var adj_button_up = "...";
    var newrow = $("...").append("...");
    quantityAdjust(newrow);
}

function quantityAdjust(newrow) {
    quantityAdjustUp(newrow);
}

function quantityAdjustUp(newrow) {
    newrow.find(".quant_adjust_up").click(function() {...});
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the input, i know exactly what is meant by this, but is just not right for the way my script is tied down with various other parts. Snippet illustrated has been simplified to post on stack. Thankyou though